# Правила произношения

Tags: фонетика

Скажите, пожалуйста, какая разница в произношении? 
"Виталию-в Италию" может быть дело в предлоге? А здесь: "смелое-смелые"?

Answer (score 1):

"Виталию-[в'и]в Италию"- [вы]- и произносится отдельно и не влияет на мягкость предыдущего согласного
"смелое [лъ]-смелые"[лы] - О подвергается редуцированию, Ы-нет.